Uniform convergence of Fourier expansion of a 3rd-differentiable function
Let $f$ be a 3rd-differentiable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the Fourier expansion $\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx)$ of $f$ convergences pointwise to $f(x)$. Show that $\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx)$ convergences uniformly to $f(x)$.
I do not know how the condition "3rd-differentiable function" is related to uniform convergence.
